# Help with shrinking creature

Tags: modeling, armature

In Lab 1 of Unit 8, I was asked to shrink the creature after I already appended it. It wont allow me to select it, it keeps turning blue. I tried everything. I pressed the "s" key but nothing worked. Thank you. I appreciate any help.

These are the instructions I am told to use:

Shrink the Creature

In these steps, you'll shrink the creature and move it to the front of the house.

Make sure that both the creature and its armature are still selected.
TIP: If the bone names are yellow or orange, then the armature is selected.
Press the S key to turn on scaling for all axes.
TIP: Press CTRL + Z if you need to undo a mistake.
Move the mouse pointer toward the creature to make it smaller until it's smaller than the house.
Left-click to stop scaling the creature.
Make sure the creature and its armature are both still selected.
Make sure that Translate Manipulator mode is selected. If not, left-click the Translate Manipulator mode button.
Move the 3D creature until it's next to the front of the house. You may need to rotate the creature using the Rotate Manipulator button.
Press the A key to deselect the creature and its armature.

Comment: What Lap of what Unit? Are you refering to an online tutorial? If so, please add a link to your question. Also make sure you haven't enabled `Manipulate center points`. You can toggle it by pressing [alt]+[,].

Comment: If you **append** an object, you can not edit it. You need to **import** the object to be able to edit it.

Comment: I teach a 3D art class that uses blender and this is the first time I have ran into this issue so I figured I would ask what others thought. I will try these things and see if they work.